# cv2 Sobel showing a different image than example

Tags: opencv, python

I am trying to understand the Sobel operator using the cv2 documentation 
https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_gradients/py_gradients.html

In order for simplicity, I pared down the example to essentials which is this.

```
img = cv2.imread("dave.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
sobelx = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=5)
```

The problem is for the given original image (dave.jpg), my output was

[image: Sobel on Dave]

Which way off from the example. What could be happening here?

If I copy paste the example, and show the image using matplotlib, the results matches closer to the one given in the documentation.

EDIT - imwrite showed a different output (matching the expected output).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is famous theme - mixing data types on OpenCV.

If you take a look at SobelDemo in tutorials of OpenCV, you can find additional functions:

```
//![convert]
// converting back to CV_8U
convertScaleAbs(grad_x, abs_grad_x);
convertScaleAbs(grad_y, abs_grad_y);
//![convert]
```

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/ImgTrans/Sobel_Demo.cpp#L57

If you want to use cv2.imshow, you can try to convert your image to CV_8U type (many methods) or use at once CV_8U if it suits your task:

```
img = cv2.imread("dave.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
sobelx = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_8U, 1, 0, ksize=5)
```

P.S. pyplot support CV_64F type and image it correctly